# Can concurrent connections, concurrent users and total users vary?

Tags: concurrency

If a web server can handle let's say 5000 concurrent connections, does this translate into 5000 concurrent users and also mean that no more than 5000 total users can be online at any given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you define an "online user" and how exactly the system works.

With a normal web page, the user is only connected to the server while downloading the page(And up to 15 seconds more if keep alive is enabled on the server).

So if i go to your website, and use one hour to read the content of a page, you may say I am online on the site for an hour, but I am only really connected to the server for the few seconds it take me to download the page. I am not connected in all the time it takes me to read the page.

So 5000 concurrent connections, mean that the server can send data to 5000 clients at the same time. No more. No less.

Comment: Ok, so as I'm understanding it, concurrent connections and users are the same, but total users may vary depending on how the web site is being used.

Comment: Every use may use several connections - modern browsers do (4 concurrent connections per domain AFAIR)